# dense rank duplicate values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, rank

So I am really happy being able to rank results based on effective dates, but currently I'm having an issue where one data element repeats (POD) while another changes based on EFFDT (DEPT).

I only want to rank unique values for Pod, and later Dept. However Pod is based on Dept, which changes more frequently. The below code gives me:

```
EENBR  PodRank POD DeptRank DeptNbr   DeptEffdt
100     1       73    1    12420      4/11/2005
100     2       73    2    12560      5/22/2005
100     3       73    3    12501      6/24/2007
200     1       12    1    50768      3/14/2005
200     2       13    2    10949      9/9/2012
300     1       73    1    12450      3/21/2005
300     2       73    2    12471      12/25/2005
300     3       73    3    12581      12/21/2008
300     4       73    4    12585      6/6/2010
300     5       73    5    12432      5/19/2013



SELECT DISTINCT 
       AL4.FULL_NAME,
       AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
       dense_rank() over (partition by AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                          order by AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) as POD_RANKING,
       AL7.POD_NBR as POD,
       row_number() over (partition by AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                          order by AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) as DEPT_RANKING,
       AL3.RECORDVALUE AS DEPT_NUMBER,
       AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS "DEPT EFFECTIVE DATE"     
  FROM T1 AL3,
       T2 AL4,
       T3 AL7 
 WHERE AL4.PERSON_ID = AL3.PERSON_ID
   AND AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = AL3.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
   AND AL3.RECORDTYPE = 'DEPARTMENT_NUMBER'
   AND AL7.DEPT_NBR = AL3.RECORDVALUE
 Order By AL4.Employee_Number;
```

Is there a function that only ranks unique values?

Comment: I don't get it. What's your expected result and why?

Comment: expected result would have the first dude ranked 1, 1, 1 as his POD# is all the same. The second one would have 1, 2 and it would be correct.

Comment: so, emp 100 stays in same pod, rank 1, 1, 1. emp 200 has 2 pods, rank 1, 2. emp 300, same pod, rank 1, 1, 1, 1, 1

Comment: ok, what if the data is like 13,13,73,73,13: should this be 1,1,2,2,1 or 1,1,2,2,3?

Comment: well i DO want it based off the Dept Effdt order, but only a new count if the Pod is unique.

Comment: Wait a minute. Isn't this the same as a simple 
                          dense_rank() over (partition by AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                          order by AL7.POD_NBR) as POD_RANKING? It's sorted by POD for ranking but sorted by date for display?

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is the analytic function `dense_rank()`:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by eenbr order by pod) as ranking
```

This is the simplest way to get what you want.  You can just add it in the `select` clause of your query.

Answer (score 0):

There's no function for this, but you can get the result when you use nested window functions:

```
SELECT dt.*,
   SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                   ORDER BY "DEPT EFFECTIVE DATE") AS POD_RANKING
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT
          AL4.FULL_NAME,
          AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,
          AL7.POD_NBR AS POD,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
                             ORDER BY AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) AS DEPT_RANKING,
          AL3.RECORDVALUE AS DEPT_NUMBER,
          AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AS "DEPT EFFECTIVE DATE",  
          CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() 
                    OVER (PARTITION BY AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER,AL7.POD_NBR
                          ORDER BY AL3.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag
     FROM T1 AL3,
          T2 AL4,
          T3 AL7 
    WHERE AL4.PERSON_ID = AL3.PERSON_ID
      AND AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = AL3.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
      AND AL3.RECORDTYPE = 'DEPARTMENT_NUMBER'
      AND AL7.DEPT_NBR = AL3.RECORDVALUE
  ) dt
ORDER BY AL4.Employee_Number;
```

Edit:
Ok, I noticed this is a overly complex version of a simple DENSE_RANK with different order, shortly before Gordon posted his answer :-)

```
dense_rank() over (partition by AL4.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER order by AL7.POD_NBR)
```

Comment: Oh this is so great. I keep rereading and trying to make what's being done fit into my pea brain.